# footer disappearing when loading iframe

Tags: css, html, iframe

I would like to have a footer in my page and I have the following code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.selitera.com" style="border: 0; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    Some footer text
  </div>

</div>

  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6fqcnmaj/

I would like to load my footer on the page always and have the available space for the iframe above the footer?

Any pointers to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the closing `</iframe>` tag

https://jsfiddle.net/6fqcnmaj/1/

Answer (score 0):

i have try to do some changes in your code and i found that when you added iframe tag it wasn't closed that's why your footer wasn't appearing. this is an example how we write Iframe tag. Have a look.

And i'm adding a solution screenshot. please have a look.
[This image is a solution of your question please look at the red border in bottom right side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TNwC.png)